# How to get specific information from a session List

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, session

```
(List<Fruit>)Session["listSession"]
```

the session  list is created in my home page.
and i would like to access information on another page

I would like to loop throw

```
if ((List<Fruit>)Session["listSession"].name == "apple ")
{
item.(access a method in my fruit class)
}else {
// do something else
}
\
```

Comment: Where is the ArrayList? `Session["listSession"]` appears to contain a `List<Fruit>`, which is not an `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 4):

```
List<Fruit> fruits = Session["listSession"] as List<Fruit>;
if(fruits != null)
{
    foreach(Fruit fruit in fruits)
    {
        if(fruit.name=="apple")
            fruit.Method();
        else
            //do something else
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A couple of points here: you can just grab the instance from the session `as` a list and keep a reference to it, then you can check it is something (not `null`) and that it contains something which is *also* something (if nullable), before grabbing a reference of that and performing desired actions:

```
var fruitList = Session["listSession"] as List<Fruit>;
if (fruitList != null && fruitList.Count > 0) 
{
    var fruit = fruitList[0];
    if (fruit != null && fruit.name == "apple ")
    { 
        fruit.Consume();
    }
}
```

That ought to help, though I'm sure you'll need to build on it to further your purpose.

Comment: You forgot `return ResponseType.Yum;`

Comment: Thank you all for the response it got my some where
here is what I done.
                
     foreach (var item in (List<Fruit>)Session["listSession"]){
                if (item.getFruitName().Equals(fruitname)){
                     //working out code here
                }else
                {
                   //error message
                }
            } 

But the next problem I have now is when I get the right fruit item i also need to check whether that fruit is edible i have a method that return true of false when u call it

Comment: but when i do 

    item.isEdible == true ; 

the compiler gives me an error operand can not be applied to method group
how do i by pass that

Comment: i know is not readable but web doesn't allow me to answer my own Question yet :(

Comment: @CMP You need to at parenthesis when calling a method: `item.isEdible() == true;` As you get further questions, I recommend you do a search or post another question if you can't find a relevant answer. :)